# Interpretation of poor quality engraving

Tags: blackletter, interpretation

(Summary of question in bold after the details.)

My interpretation of the image below (above the horizontal line) is

```
Hier ruhet in Gott
Augusta Paulmann
geborne Pabe (née Pabe)
geb. 25 Dez. 1821.
gest. 31 Marz 1882.
im Alter von (at the age of)
60 J. 3 M. & 5 Tag.
```

[image]
My skill in German is **much less than A1**, but I feel good about everything except the two upper-case "P".

I created a [*Find a Grave* entry](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/75134265/augusta-paulmann) for this, not knowing that someone else had created [their interpretation](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/55175150/sophia-faulmann).

The [operators](https://Ancestry.com) of “Find a Grave” don’t want to merge the two without additional information (but what they ask for, I’ve already given them twice).  The only thing I have doubts about is the first letter of the surname, but I am confident it is not "F"

What I have told them so far:

In the photos on both memorials, it is quite obvious that the first name is NOT “Sophia” and by comparing it with “Alter" (German for Age), the first letter is obviously “A”

The third letter is obviously “g” as in “geborne” (born).

The next to last letter can be determined “t” by comparing with “Alter”

The first letter of the surname is difficult to determine, but it is clearly not “F”  It could be a “B” but I went with “P” because there is another Paulmann in the cemetery, and no Baulmann.  It also could be “ẞ” (the capital of ß) but ẞ was not used in the 1800s and I’ve never seen an initial ß or ẞ in German.

[Cemetery records](http://parkercemeteryfw.com) do not contain this person but they do contain two “Paulman” (single “N”).  Looking through other sites, “Paulmann” is a common-enough German name but I did not find any “Baulmann"

Date of death minus age puts the birth month in December, not September, and the last letter does look like 'z' thought the first does not look like 'D'.

So **I’m looking for confirmation or correction of my analysis**, especially the first letter of the surnames (married and *geborne*).  Bonus if someone can “decrypt” what’s below the horizontal line.

Feel free to improve the tag(s)—I wasn’t sure what to call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with how you read it. If you look at the types of Fraktur on, for example, [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) it's quite clear that it's Paulmann not Faulmann. Your photo is also clearer -- from the other photo, I wouldn't have been able to clearly decide between "Rabe" and "Pabe" as the maiden name, but from your photo  it's clearly Pabe.

Unicode math symbols in two Fraktur fonts (to compare e.g. the letters D and z of "Dezember"):

```
  ℭ     ℌ ℑ         ℜ        ℨ
```

Bible verse:

"[Joh. 16, 33](https://www.bibleserver.com/LUT/Johannes16%2C33)

In der Welt habt ihr Angst, aber seid getrost; ich habe die Welt überwunden."